# Model.predict throwing TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable

Tags: numpy, keras, numpy-ndarray, predict

I am new to Python and facing few issues while implementing Neural Networks on a Earthquake prediction problem.

There is very rare material availabale online to solve this issue using neural networks, so got struck.

Please support.

Model.predict throwing TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable.

[enter link description here](https://www.drivendata.org/competitions/57/nepal-earthquake/)

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf

train_data = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\rjraj\\Desktop\\mma\\ML & AI\\Project\\train_values.csv")
train_labels = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\rjraj\\Desktop\mma\\ML & AI\\Project\\train_labels.csv")
test_labels = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\rjraj\\Desktop\\mma\\ML & AI\\Project\\test_values.csv")

X_tr = train_data
X_te = test_labels
y_tr = train_labels['damage_grade'].values

# label encoding the categorical variables
label_encoding_columns=['land_surface_condition', 'foundation_type', 'roof_type',
       'ground_floor_type', 'other_floor_type', 'position',
       'plan_configuration', 'legal_ownership_status']

# label encoding categorical columns in train dataset 
for i in label_encoding_columns:
    X_tr[i]=X_tr[i].astype("category")
    X_tr[i]=X_tr[i].cat.codes

# label encoding categorical columns in test dataset
for j in label_encoding_columns:
    X_te[j]=X_te[j].astype("category")
    X_te[j]=X_te[j].cat.codes
 
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test,y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_tr,y_tr,test_size = 0.3,random_state = 42)

X_train.shape
(182420, 39)
X_test.shape
(78181, 39)

from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
scaler.fit(X_train)
MinMaxScaler()
X_train = scaler.transform(X_train)
X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)
 
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
#from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(4, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(4, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop')
model.fit(x=X_train, y=y_train, epochs=30)
model.evaluate(X_test,y_test, verbose = 0)
model.evaluate(X_train,y_train, verbose = 0)

 
test_pred = model.predict(X_test)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-74-82e9029ecb43> in <module>
----> 1 test_pred = model.predict(X_test)

TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```